# convert sql to dsl elasticsearch query

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

i want to convert this sql query to elastic DSL query language

```
SELECT t.pk_c_c_s,
       t.fk_c_c_id,
       t.s_b_a,
       t.datetime,
       SUBSTR(t.datetime, 0, 7) m,
       (
         SELECT SUM(i.s_b_a) sarpu
         FROM TBL_C_C_S i
         WHERE substr(i.datetime, 0, 7) = substr(t.datetime, 0, 7)
           AND i.datetime <= t.datetime
           AND i.fk_c_c_id = t.fk_c_c_id
         GROUP BY SUBSTR(i.datetime, 0, 7)
        ) s
FROM TBL_C_C_S t
```

how can i convert this sql query to elasticsearch

this is my way in elasticsearch

```
POST /c_c_s_index_test/_search
{ "size":0,
  "aggs": {
    "customer": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "fk_c_c_id",
        "size": 5
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sumscore": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "s_b_a"
          }
        },
        "month": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "datetime",
            "interval": "1M",
            "min_doc_count": 1
          },
          "aggs": {
            "customer": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "s_b_a"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }    ,
        "stats_monthly_sales": {
            "extended_stats_bucket": {
                "buckets_path": "customer>sumscore" 
            }
        }
  }
```

but this just return sum of month and 
       i.datetime<=t.datetime 
does not exists in this

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current attempt.

Comment: To clarify, you're calculating daily running sum for `fk_c_c_id`?

Answer (score 1):

What you probably need is cumulative sum aggregation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-cumulative-sum-aggregation.html

So your query should look as follows:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "customer": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "fk_c_c_id",
        "size": 5
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sales_per_month": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "datetime",
            "interval": "month"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "sales": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "s_b_a"
              }
            },
            "cumulative_sales": {
              "cumulative_sum": {
                "buckets_path": "sales"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: so where is this condition   >>>> AND i.datetime <= t.datetime

Comment: `cumulative_sum` does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using ES 7, you can translate your query to dsl using the _xpack/format as follows:

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -XPOST 127.0.0.1:9200/_xpack/sql/translate?pretty -d '{"query" : "SELECT t.pk_c_c_s,
       t.fk_c_c_id,
       t.s_b_a,
       t.datetime,
       SUBSTR(t.datetime, 0, 7) m,
       (
         SELECT SUM(i.s_b_a) sarpu
         FROM TBL_C_C_S i
         WHERE substr(i.datetime, 0, 7) = substr(t.datetime, 0, 7)
           AND i.datetime <= t.datetime
           AND i.fk_c_c_id = t.fk_c_c_id
         GROUP BY SUBSTR(i.datetime, 0, 7)
        ) s
FROM TBL_C_C_S t"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the ones coming to this discussion are looking for this solution. To anyone that wants to convert his `SQL` query to `DSL`.

There is an API to translate your `SQL` query provided by `elasticsearch`

You simply send a post request for example :

```sh
POST /_sql/translate
{
  "query": "SELECT * FROM library ORDER BY page_count DESC",
  "fetch_size": 10
}
```

This will translate it into native Elasticsearch queries. Like this:

```sh
 {
  "size": 10,
  "_source": false,
  "fields": [
    {
      "field": "author"
    },
    {
      "field": "name"
    },
    {
      "field": "page_count"
    },
    {
      "field": "release_date",
      "format": "strict_date_optional_time_nanos"
    }
  ],
  "sort": [
    {
      "page_count": {
        "order": "desc",
        "missing": "_first",
        "unmapped_type": "short"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can check out the documentation [Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-translate.html).